# Fit UIView height to its content with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm using iOS 6 AutoLayout feature with [Masonry DSL](https://github.com/cloudkite/Masonry) to arrange views within UITableViewCell. This is the layout arrangements that I want to achieve:

[image: Desired UITableViewCell layout]

The `containerView` is a virtual container that should dynamically adapt its size to fit its content. With my current implementation, this is what I got instead:

[image: Current layout arrangement result]

It seems that `containerView` did get vertically centered correctly, but it has zero width and height, hence not showing up properly. How can I instruct `containerView` to fit its size to its content? Code snippets are attached below.

Thanks!

**UITableViewCell initializer**

```
- (id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]];
        self.titleLabel.text = @"ノートタイトル";

        self.coverImage = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.coverImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor carrotColor];

        self.avatarImage = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.avatarImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor emerlandColor];

        self.authorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.authorLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]];
        self.authorLabel.text = @"著者の名前";

        self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [self.containerView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
        [self.containerView addSubview:self.avatarImage];
        [self.containerView addSubview:self.authorLabel];

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.containerView];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.coverImage];

        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    }

    return self;
}
```

**UITableViewCell updateConstraints**

```
- (void)updateConstraints
{
    [super updateConstraints];

    [self.coverImage mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(20);
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(5);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView).with.offset(-5);

        make.width.equalTo(self.coverImage.mas_height).multipliedBy(0.75);
    }];

    [self.containerView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.coverImage.mas_right).with.offset(10);
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.contentView);
    }];

    [self.titleLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.containerView);
        make.top.equalTo(self.containerView);
    }];

    [self.avatarImage mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.titleLabel.mas_bottom).with.offset(5);
        make.left.equalTo(self.titleLabel);

        make.width.equalTo(@20);
        make.height.equalTo(@20);
    }];

    [self.authorLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.avatarImage.mas_right).with.offset(5);
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.avatarImage);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found out the solution to my own question. Apparently, in order for `containerView` to resize itself dynamically, we have to make sure that each elements within are connected rigidly to each other and the edges of the superview (i.e. `containerView`). For example, in VFL it should be something like this: `"V:|-10-[child1]-5-[child2]-5-|"`

So in my case, I add a new constraint `make.bottom.equalTo(self.containerView)` to `avatarImage` and now the superview knows how to height itself!